# How can i compare a time string (hours:minutes) to the server date in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, date

How can I compare a string that comes in this format:

```
var date1:String = "16:30";
```

to server clock in ActionScript 3?

Comment: Server clock? You mean the users clock right? (Accessing date in AS3 is based on the users computer time)

Comment: yes, sorry, i mean users clock

Answer (score 1):

Pretty simple. You just need to move the timestamp into a usable format using the `split()` method and then compare it to the local time using the `Date` class.

```
var time:String = "16:30";
var a:Array = time.split(":"); // == ["16", "30"]
var hours:Number = Number(a[0]);
var minutes:Number = Number(a[1]);

var curTime:Date = new Date();
var curHour:Number = curTime.hours; // 0-23 format. Adjust if needed
var curMinute:Number = curTime.minutes; //0-59 format. Adjust if needed

if (curHour > hours) {
    // current time is greater than the timestamp
}
else if (curHour == hours && curMinute > minutes) {
    // current time is greater than the timestamp
}
else if (curHour == hours && curMinute == minutes) {
    // current time is equal to the timestamp
}
else {
    // current time is less than the timestamp
}
```

You could obviously consolidate those conditions, but I did it this way to properly show the logic.

I'm unsure if there is a built in way to do this (as there is in other languages, like PHP), but I doubt it given the way AS3 handles time (there are no formatting options, no ways to add or subtract time, etc. Everything is expected to be handled by the programmer instead).